# SharePoint Search Results Does not Show Some documents

Tags: 2013, search-results

We have a problem as follows:

1) When we search for a particular document on a search center page, we get some results, but the document we are searching for is missing.

2) But when we perform the same search using a query builder we can see this document with no problems.

[image]

[image]

**Additional info:**

- We made sure that search results web part shows duplicates
- We do not use any search customization
- The document I'm searching for is published

Can someone, please, tell us why we are missing some results from the search?

**Update**
I've noticed that I can actually find this document when I put the query in quotation marks:

> "Health Project Charter Template"

But, if I remove the quotation marks from the query, I can see any document but the one I'm looking for.

[image]

Comment: Did you check whether the results webpart is using the same result source? Also, has that document been published?

Comment: I've just checked. Yes, I use the same result source and the document is published. I'm going to update the question with additional information now